# alternate portrait and landscape printing to OneNote

Tags: onenote

[**The initial description of this issue is inaccurate.  So, to avoid the nonsense, skip to the last entry starting at "Yet another edit:" below.**]

The below code snippet (from Charles Petzold) alternates between portrait and landscape when printing multi-page documents.  When printing to "Microsoft Print to PDF" or "Send to OneNote 2016", the 1st page is in landscape mode and subsequent pages alternate as expected. When printing to "Send to OneNote" or "OneNote", all pages are in landscape orientation.  Changing the logic to start with portrait mode, results in all pages printing in portrait mode.

```
    void OnQueryPageSettings(object obj, QueryPageSettingsEventArgs qpsea)
    {
        if (qpsea.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.LandscapeAngle != 0)
        qpsea.PageSettings.Landscape ^= true;
    }
```

## Green works; Red otherwise:

[image]

And the question would be, "Why?" or, "Just on my system?" (Windows 10 with Office 365 Personal).

---

Edit:  Actually, after a closer look, the OneNote entries did alternate, but the graphics size changed between the orientations.  On other words, OneNote 2016 presents the same size "paper" in either orientation, but the new improved OneNote changes "paper" size depending upon orientation. So, the OneNote presentation of the landscape has the same width as the portrait presentation.

## Landscapes vs rotated portraits:

[image: Landscapes vs rotated portraits:]

---

Edit again:

If anything, the graphics size is more accurate in the ew OneNote:
OneNote 2016
Letter: Height=1100, Width=850.  grfx: Height=792, Width=1017 (Landscape)
Letter: Height=1100, Width=850.  grfx: Height=1042, Width=792 (Portrait)

OneNote
Letter: Height=1100, Width=850.  grfx: Height=750, Width=1000 (Landscape)
Letter: Height=1100, Width=850.  grfx: Height=1000, Width=750 (Portrait)

However, the presentation of the OneNote output is not consistently scaled:

## OneNote Snips Side-by-Side

[image: Side-by-Side]enter image description here]

---

Yet another edit:

Having learned that printing to OneNote actually is done via the XPS printer, I made an XPS printout and used the XPS Viewer to print using "Send to OneNote 2016" and "Send to OneNote".  The XPS file alternates from Portrait to Landscape to Portrait.  When displayed in either version of OneNote, the "Send to OneNote 2016" display has consistent scaling for each page; the "Send to OneNote" display forces the landscape page to have the same width as the portrait page:

## Pictorially:

[image: A picture]

## The XPS file for the curious:

[XPS file on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjUees71jgJMgoU5WprB49z4R4M0vw)